# xcode 7.3 swift What UI views make up the structure of this display?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, uitoolbar

I'm trying to figure out the structure of this iphone app display, but for the life of me I can't work out a convincing structure. I think my understanding of Nav Bars, Views, Toolbars, maybe embedded toolbars, icons, etc is just too weak to figure this layout out.

[image]

I've read endless Apple doc, and net tutorials, but none of them address things as pretty (and complex?) as this layout, simple as it looks.

I've spent hours trying to build a stack view for the top bar, with two left/right icon buttons, with an embedded toolbar (+ 3 bar button items) in the middle. But with zero success -- I posted a separate question on why my embedded toolbar with 3 buttons disappears in the stack view with distribution=Fill Proportionately.

Could anyone give me a convincing layout structure that I can try? And how about the dark blue color, with a sunken border around the 3 center buttons, and a darker background for the selected button? (Is the selected button a separate image from it's unselected state?)

And then the second collection -- is it a view with rounded corners behind the controls, or is it something else? How might I space out the left/right arrows with the long date string button in the middle (not with a horizontal stack view, I'm guessing). And the bottom buttons -- could that be a segmented control?

If you could identify the building blocks for me, that would help. Or maybe a tutorial or doc somewhere, or a code project example somewhere that I could study? (Wouldn't it be wonderful if someone had a sample app with this stuff that I could just load and learn from... :-) PS. I've also looked around the net for sample open source apps, and found probably 50, but none that I could recognize as being on target, or in swift.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The top area is probably a UINavigationBar, and the three things in it are its left bar button item, its title view, and its right bar button item.

The bottom part is a UITableView in Grouped style. It has two sections. The first section consists of one cell in which is laid out the whole four-subview structure. Then there's another section whose header title is "today" and each of the things after that is a cell.

The two "make a choice" rectangles, both at the top and in the first cell, are UISegmentedControls.

Comment: Thank you. Boy, I didn't know you could put all those "make a choice" segmented controls in one cell. A clarification please, when you say the top bar is a Nav bar, why would it be a Nav Bar when no navigation is going on? Second, when you say "the title view" in the Nav bar, how does a (text?) title get turned into 3 toolbar buttons? Thanks

Comment: Use of nav bar as top bar is common even if there is no navigation.  Title view is different from title.

Comment: I see you put my image inline, thank you. I'm not allowed to do that yet, being a newbie. Is a "title view" some special object? I can't find it in xcode, or on the net. How would I make one like the one in the screenshot?

Comment: @Kevin titleView will be a property of the navigation bar.